# iOS core location finding the distance travelled

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I want to calculate total distance covered by person using core location.User press start button it will show calculated distance on iphone screen .It also give some updated data after certain period of time.even though the person didn't made any movement it still shows  some distance. Can any one help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble calculating accurate total walking/running distance using CLLocationManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779074/having-trouble-calculating-accurate-total-walking-running-distance-using-cllocat)